# How to Handle API with Session (XML 307 Response) in PHP

Tags: php, xml, api, soap

I have situation here. Currently I developed a web, and need to make a function to communicate with device API. Now I'm stuck with **307 (Temporary Redirect)**.

So, the flow is, first I need to make a session with login function. If login success it will give response **307 (Temporary Redirect)**, and there's Location in the response header (sessionId). So, to POST another request, we need to follow the Location (sessionId). When I tried in Postman for always success for login function to get Location (SessionId), but to POST another request from those Location sometimes success and sometimes not success. I tried to make it in PHP, for login always success and get the Location, but when POST another requst it always failed.

Here's the XML function for Login :

```
 POST / HTTP/1.1
 Host: 111.222.123.123:8001
 <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:lgi="http://www.qwerty.org/func/LGI">
     <soapenv:Header/>
     <soapenv:Body>
         <lgi:LGI>
             <lgi:OPNAME>username</lgi:OPNAME>
             <lgi:PWD>password</lgi:PWD>
         </lgi:LGI>
     </soapenv:Body>
 </soapenv:Envelope>
```

This is header response from login function :

```
HTTP/1.1 307 Temporary Redirect
Location: http://111.222.123.123:8001/00112233
Server: Qwerty web server
Content-Type: text/xml; charset="utf-8"
Content-Length: 411
```

**00112233** is the Location (SessionId) to POST another request. But again, If from Postman, sometimes success, and sometimes not success. And if from PHP always failed to POST request after get Location (SessionId)

Here's my PHP script for **Login** fucntion :

```
    $soapUrl = "http://111.222.123.123:8001/";

    $xml_post_string1 = '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:lgi="http://www.qwerty.org/func/LGI">
                            <soapenv:Header/>
                            <soapenv:Body>
                                <lgi:LGI>
                                    <lgi:OPNAME>username</lgi:OPNAME>
                                    <lgi:PWD>password</lgi:PWD>
                                </lgi:LGI>
                            </soapenv:Body>
                        </soapenv:Envelope>';

    $headers1 = array(
                    "Content-type: text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"",
                    "Accept: text/xml",
                    "Cache-Control: no-cache",
                    "Pragma: no-cache",
                    "SOAPAction: http://www.qwerty.org/func/LGI", 
                    "Content-length: ".strlen($xml_post_string1),
                );

        $url = $soapUrl;

        $ch1 = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
        curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
        curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_post_string1);
        curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers1);

        curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);

        $response1 = curl_exec($ch1); 

        $header_size = curl_getinfo($ch1, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
        $header = substr($response1, 0, $header_size);

        $break1= explode('/', $header);
        $break2= preg_split('/[\s]+/', $break1[4]);
        $sessionId = $break2[0];
```

This is my **request after got the Location / SessionId** :

```
    $soapUrlToken1 = "http://111.222.123.123:8001/";
    $soapUrlToken2 = $soapUrlToken1.$sessionId ;

    $xml_post_string2 = '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sh="http://www.qwerty.org/func/SH_SUB">
                           <soapenv:Header/>
                           <soapenv:Body>
                              <sh:SH_SUB>
                                 <sh:USER>USERNAME</sh:USER>
                                 <sh:DETAIL>TRUE</sh:DETAIL>
                              </sh:SH_SUB>
                           </soapenv:Body>
                        </soapenv:Envelope>';

    $headers2 = array(
                    "POST /$token HTTP/1.1",
                    "Host: 111.222.123.123:8001",
                    "Content-type: text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"",
                    "Accept: text/xml",
                    "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate",
                    "User-Agent: City Commons-HttpClient/3.1",
                    "SOAPAction: http://www.qwerty.org/func/SH_SUB",

                    "Content-length: ".strlen($xml_post_string2),
                );

    $urlToken = $soapUrlToken2;
    //echo "<br />".$urlToken."<br />";

    $ch2 = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_URL, $urlToken);
    curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
    curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_post_string2);
    curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers2);

    $response2 = curl_exec($ch2); 

    $response3 = str_replace("<SOAP-ENV:Body>","",$response2);
    $response4 = str_replace("</SOAP-ENV:Body>","",$response3);
    $parser2 = simplexml_load_string($response4);
```

In php the response always about sessionId is Invalid or timed out. I already ask with API team, they explanation only about **The session and port must maintain to make another request after login**

So what is best solution to deal with **307 (Temporary Redirect)** in PHP?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already found a solution. I don't need use `curl_init()` again after get the Location (SessionId). `curl_init()` will **initializes a new session** that is the problem, the Location (sessionId) already got before will be destroyed with `curl_init()`